# Passing Parameters and Running Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I'm unsure if what I'm trying to do is possible. I have a PowerShell script that takes three arguments. In a perfect world, I'd collect the necessary information in a web form and pass it to the script, which would then run.

I don't know if this is even possible, but I can't find anything that definitively tells me no. I'd need it to be cross-browser capable (we have some Macs) so I can't just do an IE-only fix.

This is also internal only, so I'm less concerned about some security risks. It will be behind our firewall.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your Powershell code and where are the arguments being passed from? Have you got the webform at least trying to open the powershell script?

Comment: Haven’t started anything with the code. Can put the script anywhere, including the web server. I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: [About Functions CmdletBindingAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-6) will get you started with allowing Powershell to accept parameters. I recommend searching the other answers to have a look at the answer that have parameter bindings. Looks like `param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]`

Comment: So where / how should I host the form? What language gets that in the script?

Comment: @JoeFedorowicz are you using .net code for the webform?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the question, but for collecting the necessary information in a web form and pass it to the script, which would then run I user [PowerShell Web Server](http://poshserver.net/index.html) (tag : poshserver in stackoverflow). Sources are available, so I even implements Jobs for long scripts.